# How to implement bing maps api in ember-cli using a component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, bing-maps

I successfully implemented bing maps api in my ember-cli app but everything is in the index.html file, so what I would like to do is implement bing maps in a component to be able to change the longitude and latitude variables with values I get from a fixture or json. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this and created a simple bing map addon for ember-cli, for the benefit of everyone.
[Here](https://github.com/cometaworks/ember-cli-bing-map) is the link for anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know ember-cli except from what I've read while looking to help you on the web, but it appears that it is web application, so you will be able to use the Bing Maps AJAX V7 control.

To get started, I would recommend to go through the MSDN articles available from Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx

Let us know if you need any more help cause your question is somewhat really not precise.